# how to use cells for a Hyperlink destination/path and workbook name VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

I have a folder on the desktop

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\folder1\folder2\
```

In workbook 1 have column A which was used to create folders within folder 2.
Column N was then used to create filenames for each newly created workbook.

Every Row became a new workbook. (~3200 Workbooks, each in their own folder)

How can I either write a VBA or a Formula to quickly create the hyperlinks.
The reasoning is that the Master workbook will be used to narrow down the the search results and give immediate access to that location of the database.

the path I have is,

```
C:\Users\ME\Desktop\folder1\folder2\ & Column A & "/" & Column N & ".xlsm"
```

I tried using a formula

```
=HYPERLINK('C':\Users\ME\Desktop\folder1\folder2\ & [@SITE] & "/" & [@FULLNAME] & ".xlsm",[@FULLNAME])
```

This doesn't seam to work, the Cells I'm referencing is stated as the column headers. When I hit enter the entire column downward was then filled with "#NAME?" and a error stating "the formula contains unrecognized text"

Comment: You should post the code you use to create what you describe in your question. It's much easier to help you if we can see your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flip "/" into a "\"

Also look at this example for guidance:

```
=HYPERLINK(C10&"\"&A10&"\"&B10&".xlsx")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use formula like this in New column and use it for the whole range:

```
=HYPERLINK("C:\Users\ME\Desktop\folder1\folder2\ & $A2 & "/" & $N2 & ".xlsm","PathToFile_" & $N2)
```